# Is there a tool for collapsing output of a command base on regex?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Let’s say I have a command that outputs the state of some application. This command runs forver (or until C-c) and outputs a single line when something happens inside the application. It outputs the following format

```
State N: Stuff M happened
```

I want a program, let's call it `collapse_prog`, that takes the lines outputed the command, based on the regex I give to it, to overwrite the previous state. For example, let's say the input regex is State (\d+), I run the following command

```
my_command | collapse_prog
```

and the `my_command` outputs

```
State 1: Stuff A happened
State 2: Stuff B happened
```

then the `collapse_prog` should display as is, but after the `my_command` outputs another line

```
State 1: Stuff C happened
```

then the `collapse_prog` should have the following output

```
State 1: Stuff C happened
State 2: Stuff B happened
```

Is there such a program out there already?

Comment: If the `collapse_prog` has already outputted two lines, how should it overwrite the first line? Is this supposed to be solved using terminal escape sequences to move the cursor around on the screen? It seems as if you want to write an interactive frontend to some existing software.

Comment: well, it can behave like `watch` also

Comment: So, something like saving all the output of the command and then clearing the screen and reparsing all saved output whenever a single line is produced by the command (or after a certain time)?

Comment: yes, whether it buffers or not is implemetation details, but the general idea is that

Answer (score 1):

Very basic solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
$ program | txr stcoll.tl
```

Where `stcoll.tl` is:

```
(let ((states (hash)))
  (whilet ((line (get-line)))
    (when-match `State @s: @status` line
      (set [states s] status)
      (dohash (s status states)
        (put-line `State @s: @status`))
      (put-string `\e[@(len states)A`)
      (flush-stream *stdout*))))
```

How it works is that the most recent status for each state is kept in a hash table, keyed on the state ID. Each time we get a state line, we update the hash, and then print it.  After printing it, we move the cursor back that many lines using the `ESC[<n>A` VT100/ANSI escape sequence.  This assumes the terminal window is tall enough for all the states, which is fair for what is supposed to be very simple interactive watching tool.

A more sophisticated program would poll standard input with a timeout, say of one second. Or configurable. Then each time through the input loop, whether a line was received or whether there was a timeout, check whether the hash has changed and if so, whether the refresh period since the last refresh has expired. In that case, refresh the display.

Such a program will more efficiently update the display when the input is arriving quickly.

Here it is:

```
(let* ((states (hash))
       (last-time 0)
       (hash-touched nil)
       (unbuf-stdin (open-fileno (fileno *stdin*) "u"))
       (poll-list (vec (cons unbuf-stdin poll-in))))
  (while t
    (if (poll poll-list 1000)
      (let ((line (get-line unbuf-stdin)))
        (when-match `State @s: @status` line
          (set [states s] status
               hash-touched t))))
    (let ((now (time)))
      (when (and hash-touched (>= (- now last-time) 1))
        (dohash (s status states)
          (put-line `State @s: @status`))
        (put-string `\e[@(len states)A`)
        (flush-stream *stdout*)
        (set hash-touched nil
             last-time now)))))
```

This updates in nice one second intervals, even though the program is spewing. I'm using this program to generate test inputs. It randomly increments one of 20 states and prints the update, with random pauses:

```
(let* ((nstates 20)
       (states (vector nstates 0)))
  (while t
    (let ((choice (rand nstates)))
      (inc [states choice])
      (put-line `State @choice: @[states choice]`)
      (flush-stream *stdout*)
      (if (zerop (rand 4) )
        (usleep (rand 500000))))))
```

Comment: this is very interesting, thanks for introducing me to a new programming language. However, the solution requires too exotic setup, I think will try to program it myself.